# how to add css property for a tr depending on td

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to apply class to tr  depending on td cell  value in a table .

my html

```
<table class="k-focusable">
 <tr>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Favorite color</th>
<th> status</th>
 </tr>
  <td>James</td>
  <td>red</td>
<td>false</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>blue</td>
  <td>true</td>
 </tr>
</table>

var cellIndexMapping = { 2: true };
$("table.k-focusable tbody tr").each(function (rowIndex) {
            $(this).find("td").each(function (cellIndex) {
                if (x[cellIndex]) {
                    var c = $(this).text();
                    if (($.trim(c) == "false") || ($.trim(c) == "null")) {
                        $("table.k-focusable tbody tr").find("td").addClass("hover");
                    }
                }
            });
        });

.hover
{
 font-weight:bold
}
```

when i am doing this, every row  is having this class hover.But i want that class to be add only if the td value is false or null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$("table.k-focusable tbody tr").each(function(rowIndex) {
    var $td = $(this).find("td:eq(2)");
    var c = $td.text();
    if (($.trim(c) == "false") || ($.trim(c) == "null")) {
        $td.closest('tr').addClass("hover");
    }
});​
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/tGYjj/1/)**

You don't need the second `$.each` to iterate over the td's in the first place.
You can then reference the `td` you want to change with this

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
$("table.k-focusable tbody tr td:contains('false')")
```

Comment: i want to apply this class only to 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

In your test `if (($.trim(c) == "false") ...`, you pick all `td`. You just have to apply the class to the current cell since you are already in a loop over the cells :

```
$(this).addClass("hover");
```